# My Website displays properly in every browser except Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, cross-browser

Chrome, Safari and Opera display my website without trouble, though Firefox removes the top section including the menu. The center of the section is entirely removed and replaced with white. I'm not at all sure what the issue is.

Any suggestions?

Website under development and can be found: http://www.jw.potatomou.se/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the code that is causing the problem

Comment: Your html is a bit off, you are ending your body tag and then starting the footer, that is not the way to do it. Put all of your html inside the body.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that footer part, thanks for that.

Comment: As it stands your question has little value for future references and should be closed as to localized. Linking to the website doesn't change that, because it can (and probably will) change, so nobody will be able to see the original problem. Please edit your question so that others may learn from your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .row has a height of 1% and is set to overflow:hidden. You also need to clear floats for them to take up presentational space. This should do it:

```
.row {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0.5em;
    min-height: 1%;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 2% 1em 0;
} 
.row:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: This sorts it perfectly! Actually the code there isn't mine, it's part of http://www.fitgrd.com. I wonder if we should let them know there's a problem! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -2):

This is browser compatibility issue ..you have to used CSS reset 
you can found here is the link http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Please indicate the exact CSS issue. Using a CSS reset *might* solve the problem (though it is not mandatory) but it doesn't explain what the actual issue is.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that doesn't solve it. I've already got a reset section at the top of my CSS.

Comment: You can't solve everything with reset stylesheets. Browsers are not _that_ different.